# Segmentation fault while reading larger .bmp file

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when I compile.

Something to do with memory allocation in the first for loop when I try to populate the table array in main() I think?

It works if I call a smaller file but not with the 'bigger' table.bmp file.

I do not understand why? (I am pretty new to this)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

unsigned char *read_bmp(char *fname,int* _w, int* _h)
{
    unsigned char head[54];
    FILE *f = fopen(fname,"rb");

    // BMP header is 54 bytes
    fread(head, 1, 54, f);

int w = head[18] + ( ((int)head[19]) << 8) + ( ((int)head[20]) << 16) + ( ((int)head[21]) << 24);
int h = head[22] + ( ((int)head[23]) << 8) + ( ((int)head[24]) << 16) + ( ((int)head[25]) << 24);

// lines are aligned on 4-byte boundary
int lineSize = (w / 8 + (w / 8) % 4);
int fileSize = lineSize * h;

unsigned char *img = malloc(w * h), *data = malloc(fileSize);

// skip the header
fseek(f,54,SEEK_SET);

// skip palette - two rgb quads, 8 bytes
fseek(f, 8, SEEK_CUR);

// read data
fread(data,1,fileSize,f);



// decode bits
int i, j, k, rev_j;
for(j = 0, rev_j = h - 1; j < h ; j++, rev_j--) {
    for(i = 0 ; i < w / 8; i++) {
        int fpos = j * lineSize + i, pos = rev_j * w + i * 8;
        for(k = 0 ; k < 8 ; k++)
            img[pos + (7 - k)] = (data[fpos] >> k ) & 1;
    }`enter code here`
}

free(data);
*_w = w; *_h = h;
return img;
}

int main()
{

int w, h, i, j, x, y, b=0, butpos=0;

//Get array data

unsigned char* imgtable = read_bmp("table.bmp", &w, &h);
int table[w][h];

printf("w=%i \n", w);
printf("h=%i \n", h);

//make table array

 for(j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
{

    for(i = 0 ; i < w ; i++)
        table[j][i] = imgtable[j * w + i] ? 0 : 1;

}
```

Comment: Now would probably be a good time to start learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: I tried to use Valgrind but got a configure error

Comment: Start out with gdb - that should take you quickly and easily to the problem.

Comment: I ran gdb and got the following -                                                                    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_alloca ()
    at /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm:45
45      in /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygwin.asm

Comment: It does not really help, i'm still not sure what the problem is, can anybody help?

Comment: Don't just "run gdb" - step through the code, examine your local variables at each step and see if the code is really behaving as intended. It looks to me as if you're trying to read more bytes than actually exist in the file, for starters, and there are probably other bugs beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to allocate the image data on the stack.  When the image is too big, this causes a stack overflow.  This code is the problem:

```
int main()
{

    int w, h, i, j, x, y, b=0, butpos=0;

    //Get array data

    unsigned char* imgtable = read_bmp("table.bmp", &w, &h);
    int table[w][h];  // <-- HERE
    ...
```

This is using a feature of C99 called *variable-length arrays* (VLAs), where an array of non-constant size (in this case, a 2D `w` by `h` array, where `w` and `h` are not known until runtime) is allocated on the stack.

The mention of the function `_alloca` in your stack trace should have cued you to this -- the [`alloca(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) function allocates a dynamic amount of memory on the stack.  And since you're not explicitly calling `alloc()` anywhere yourself, it must be coming from a usage of VLAs.

The fix, as you mentioned, is to allocate the image data on the heap, not on the stack:

```
data = malloc(h * w * sizeof(*data));
table = malloc(h * sizeof(*table));
for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    table[i] = &data[i * w];
}

...

free(table);
free(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having a similar problem, it seemed to be a problem with memory allocation.

the following solution below worked for me;

```
unsigned char* img = read_table("table.bmp", &w, &h); 
int *data;
int **table;   

data = malloc(h * w * sizeof(*data));
table = malloc(h * sizeof(*table));
for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
    table[i] = &data[i * w];
}
```